# Teradata: Difference between ANSI and TERA modes with respect to record insertion

Tags: database-connection, teradata

I am working on an application that takes records from Hadoop and inserts them into Teradata via sqoop(JDBC).

I am using TERA mode for the connection and the target table is SET table. I am getting duplicate row issue for some datasets.

As far as I know TERA mode is supposed to ignore duplicate records while doing inserts. Can somebody please confirm the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a **SET** table in **TERA** mode in Teradata there are two scenarios:

1.) For set table **table_name**(which throw **Duplicate Row Exception**):

```
insert into DBName.table_name(id,name) values(1,'Mukesh'); //Success

insert into DBName.table_name(id,name) values(1,'Mukesh'); //Failure

insert into DBName.table_name(id,name) values(1,'mukesh'); //Failure
```

In TERA mode it is not case sensitive, so it treats the records as same. And also throw **Duplicate Row Exception**.

2.) For set table table_name(which do not throw **Duplicate Row Exception**):

```
insert into DBName.table_name(id,name) select id,name from DBName.table_name2;
```

If there are records in **DBName.table_name2** which are already in table **DBName.table_name** and if we try to execute the above query, it will simply ignores the **Duplicate Row Exception** and also it will not insert anything it the  table **DBName.table_name**.

Also in **ANSI** mode, there will be **Duplicate Row Exception** for both the above scenarios.

Comment: So in ANSI mode for example (1) statement #3 will work since its in different case?